# what is the best way of finding the execution time of SOQL query?

Tags: soql

what is the best and reliable way to find the time taken by SOQL query to execute ?
can we rely on SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN and SOQL_EXECUTE_END events in the debug log and compare their timestamps to get the execute time of the query ?

Comment: If your goal is to understand or evaluate soql performance you may also be interested in the soql explain api pilot: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_query_explain.htm

Comment: you can evaluate soql performance by using the query plan tool from Dev Console. I am more interested in finding how much time query is taking to execute in real time

Answer (score 6):

I'd declare a datetime variable just before the query, then do a datetime variable just after the query, then compare the two values.

Something like:

```
datetime qryStart = datetime.now();
database.query(<query string>);
datetime qryEnd = datetime.now();
//debug number of seconds the query ran
system.debug(logginglevel.WARN, (qryEnd.getTime() - qryStart.getTime()) /1000);
```

Comment: Debug log's events SOQL_EXECUTE_BEING and SOQL_EXECUTE_END also has the timestamp. the question is which one to trust ?

Comment: That wouldn't be to hard to figure out. If you debug both of the timestamps and compare them to SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN and SOQL_EXECUTE_END you'd have an answer very quickly. My method does save you a bit of work by doing math for you.

Comment: Update: The timestamps are different between my method and the event logs which would be the difference between declaring the variables and the query starting/ending. This suggests that the timestamps on SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN and SOQL_EXECUTE_END are more accurate. However, we're talking milliseconds. That may or may not be a big deal to you.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the Profiling category on debug logs to FINEST exposes query execution times in the ending of debug logs.

For example the overly-simple anonymous apex:
`List<Contact> c = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE Id != null];`

This results in a debug log which right before the end contains:

```
21:04:45.258|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN
21:04:45.258|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|SOQL operations|
AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1: [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE Id != null]: executed 1 time in 4 ms

21:04:45.258|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOSL operations
21:04:45.258|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for DML operations
21:04:45.258|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|method invocations|
External entry point: public static void execute(): executed 1 time in 7 ms

21:04:45.258|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this tool https://apextimeline.herokuapp.com/